# How to use StyleSelector without losing the global style set?

Tags: wpf, xaml, wpf-controls, telerik

lets say that I have a global style set for ItemsContainer control, and this style is applied well during runtime. Now I have a requirement to paint Row background for each row, based on some condition. For this I decided to use RowStyleSelector.

```
<RadTreeListView RowStyleSelector="{StaticResource ActivityRowStyleSelector}" />

<Style x:Key="xxxTreeListViewStyle" TargetType="telerik:TreeListViewRow">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FFFFE1C4" />
</Style>

<local:xxxRowStyleSelector x:Key="xxxRowStyleSelector"
                           FailureStyle="{StaticResource xxxTreeListViewStyle}"
                           .../>
```

But this overrides the global style that I set for row, and I just want to change Background property to existing style.

And another question is: how would I apply this change to a particular cell, not row?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [Style.BasedOn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.style.basedon.aspx) property to "inherit" one style from another. Use it like this (where `RowGlobalStyle` is the name of the global style you've created previously):

```
<Style x:Key="xxxTreeListViewStyle" TargetType="telerik:TreeListViewRow"
    BasedOn="{StaticResource RowGlobalStyle}">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FFFFE1C4" />
</Style>
```

Comment: This style is in another xaml file, which I merge together in app resources. How can I use BasedOn with style that is in another xaml file?

Comment: @Goran I'm not sure, I haven't done much with multiple XAML files in one program. Do you get a compiler error if you try to use BasedOn with a style from another file?

Comment: yes I get cannot find resource exception. I was able to solve that one, it seems that order of xaml files while merging is of importance. Anyway, it still doesn't work. Now I have totally opposite results: now my custom style is applied, but the setter Property="Background" doesn't do anything... Previously it was that background was changed, but style was lost.